# Can't seem to get my list view to open from a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I have a sub menu from my main menu with a button that opens a listview activity, even though there are no errors detected in the code it still crashing upon clicking. I've tried a few things from creating a custom array to using an auto generated generic list. I am certain it is a problem with the layouts...

The activity with the button(abbutton) that should create the list:

```
package org.myscores.www;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class sundayopen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle myscores) {
         super.onCreate(myscores);
         setContentView(R.layout.sundayopen);
         ImageButton hb1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homebutton1);
         ImageButton sbc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.satlidopen);
         ImageButton ab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.abbutton);
         sbc.setOnClickListener(this);
         hb1.setOnClickListener(this);
         ab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


         public void onClick(View v){
             switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.homebutton1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                 break;
             case R.id.satlidopen:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,stat.class));
                break;
             case R.id.abbutton:
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, ablist.class));

             }
         }
}
```

The xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scoreback" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scorebox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/scorebox"
        android:src="@drawable/scorebox" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/satlid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/satlid"
        android:src="@drawable/slid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/frilid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thulid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/satlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/frilid"
        android:src="@drawable/flid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thulid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/frilid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/thulid"
        android:src="@drawable/tlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/homebutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/homebutton"
        android:src="@drawable/homebut1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/wedlid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thulid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/thulid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/wedlid"
        android:src="@drawable/wlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tuelid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wedlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tuelid"
        android:src="@drawable/tlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/monlid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pillboxm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tuelid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/monlid"
        android:src="@drawable/mlid" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/adbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/abbutton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/adbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/adbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/abbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cobutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/abbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/antibiotic_buton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bppressure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/monlid"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/adbutton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bpbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/bpbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/satlidopen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/monlid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/monlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/satlidopen"
        android:src="@drawable/satlidopen" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cobutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/satlidopen"
        android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wedlid"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cobutton"
        android:src="@drawable/cobutton" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

The listview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
     <ListView  
         android:id="@android:id/scre"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         />
     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Empty set"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
```

the listview java:

```
package org.myscores.www;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class screj extends ListActivity {
        String[] listItems = {"week", "month", 
                              "yead", "day"};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pointlist);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
}
}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="org.myscores.www"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/> 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:enabled="true">

    <activity
        android:name="org.myscores.www.Splashscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">    
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />        
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity   
        android:name="org.myscores.www.Splashscreen2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>       
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>                  
    <activity
        android:name="org.myscores.www.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
     <activity      
        android:name="org.myscores.www.difference"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>   
      <activity          
        android:name="org.iimed.www.scoreboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>   
    <activity
        android:name="org.myscores.www.sundayopen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity
        android:name="org.myscores.www.pointlist"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

     </application>
    </manifest>
```

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: on which button you want to start which activity and have you made an entry for the activityin manifest? and post the stacktrace

Comment: @user2873962 Post your stack trace and logcat

Comment: it looks like you have copy pasted code from somewhere

Comment: @Raghunandan I mentioned logcat as,shows the message based on the stacktrace

Comment: yeah, raghunandan the listview java and xml. I tried to edit a listview code to fit my project as i didn't know where to start

Comment: @user2873962 did you try the suggestion in my post? if so what does the stack trace say? does it still crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The activity with the button(abbutton) that should create the list:

I beleive you want to start the list activity on clicking `abbutton`

Change this

```
case R.id.abbutton:
      startActivity(new Intent(this, ablist.class));
```

To

```
case R.id.abbutton:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, screj.class));
```

coz

```
public class screj extends ListActivity { 
// activity name is scresj not ablist
```

And Make sure you have this in manifest

```
 <activity
    android:name="org.myscores.www.screj"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
 </activity>
```

Also for stat activity

```
 <activity
    android:name="org.myscores.www.stat"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
 </activity>
```

Edit :

`ListActivity` has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id `"@android:id/list"` (or list if it's in code)

So you need to have the below in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"  // id must be @android:id/list
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         />
     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Empty set"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Always have class Name starts with caps like `Screj`

Not sure but you have `<activity

        android:name="org.iimed.www.scoreboard"`. I believe you have a activity by name `scoreboard` in `org.myscores.www package`. SO change to `<activity

        android:name="org.myscores.www.scoreboard"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turns out I had some left over package info from a test tutorial that I changed to myscores, then in the manifest I was declaring the wrong 'screj' as both xml and java were named the same and in split packages, I renamed the class to a capital 'Screej' and it's good as gold now. Thanks a bunch, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your ablist activity isn't declared in your manifest. You have to add it as you add your MainActivity for example.

```
<activity
            android:name="org.myscores.www.ablist"
             android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```